# How to get a subcolumn under a column in excel using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am parsing an excel spreadsheet using pandas:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filePath)
df = xl.parse("Sheet")
df1 = df['Col1']
```

How do I get the subcolumns `A` and `B` of `Col1` if they look like this:

```
 Col1
A    B
1    2
3    4
1    9
```

The numbers are just data.

Desired Output is a dataframe:

```
A   B
1   2
3   4
1   9
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing, is Col1 in excel `A1` with A in `A2` and the numbers underneath, and then B is in `B2` with the numbers underneath?

Comment: `Col1` takes up two columns (merged two columns) A1 and B1. `A` takes up A2 and `B` takes up B2

Comment: Can you share the desired output?

Comment: is col1 currently a multiindex? Or is row1 in your df `A    B` and row2 `1    2`? Basically do A and B occupy different columns in your df, or is it 1 column represented as a string

Comment: what happens if you do; `df1.reset_index()`

Comment: `Col1` is in row1 where `A` and `B` are in row 2. `Col1` are two columns that are merged together for that row only.

Comment: `df1.reset_index()` did not work....

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this worked quite well:

```
new = m.Col1.str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

This will split the values inside the Column into two separate columns.

```
new2=new.iloc[1:].copy(deep=True)
new2.set_axis(new.iloc[0].values, axis=1,inplace=True)
```

And the above two commands will first create a copy of all the values except 1 row which will later be used as to set as column names.

Final output:

```
   A     B
1  1     2
2  3     4
3  1     9
```

Edit:

---

Well when I called the file you just shared and used the same commands by which you were calling the excel sheet, I got the columns separately only.

This is the code and output:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('test1.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df1 = df['Col1']
```

And just see how df is coming as:

```
print(df)

   Col1 Unnamed: 1  Col2 Unnamed: 3
0     A          B     A          B
1   434       4343  7657         45
2   193        217    53        284
3  7634         32  1754        412
```

It's giving unnamed because it's not able to capture a column name as that cell above has been merged. But the column names can be easily changed by using set_axis, code for that is:

```
df.set_axis(df.iloc[0].values,axis=1)
df=df.iloc[1:]
print(df)

      A     B     A    B
1   434  4343  7657   45
2   193   217    53  284
3  7634    32  1754  412
```

Does this solves your problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake. I create a pseudo dataframe and named it as m.

Here it is:
m=pd.DataFrame({'Col1':["A    B","1    2","3    4","1    9"]})

Comment: Ok so my dataframe is called `xl`. When I tried doing that (`xl.Col1.str.aplit(...)`), it is saying `xl` has no attribute `Col1`

Comment: In that case your data doesn't have a column, named Col1. I was just performing it on the name I saw on your question.

Can you share the excel file or sample of it via Google Drive? I can try on your actual data.

Comment: It says file not found

Comment: Sorry I reloaded it again...should work now. I think it allows only one download

Comment: No jess, it still says, file not found. I suggest use Google Drive or Dropbox.

Comment: Ok I uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVUAbupINet2QKb2Ady8FHaJALGwzvAp/view?usp=sharing Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am getting the desired output while importing the file itself that you sent me.

Wait i'll make an edit and show you what I am getting

Comment: Take a look at the answer Jess

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the first row of the file:

```
>>> df = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx', skiprows=1)
>>> df
      A     B   A.1  B.1
0   434  4343  7657   45
1   193   217    53  284
2  7634    32  1754  412
```

In case you are only interested in a certain sheet, define `sheet_name=` when calling `.read_excel()`. See the function's [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for more options.